# How to make an stateful web service with ejb3?

Tags: web-services, ejb, jax-ws

This is my webservice...
With EJB3 + Jboss AS7

```
@Stateful
@WebService(serviceName = "teste")
public class TesteWSImpl implements TesteWS {

    private List<String> strings;

    public TesteWSImpl() {
        strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @WebMethod
    @Override
    public List<String> add(String string) {
        strings.add(string);
        return strings;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("INIT WEB SERVICE. "
                + getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("DESTROY WEB SERVICE. "
                + getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }

}
```

but in my jboss 7 endpoint is not found.. any idea? I need keep state of my client

Comment: is keeping the state on the client side an option? (like a token so you know your're already authenticated for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not annotate an stateful session bean with @WebService annotation, it is [only available](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbor.html) to stateless.